# Typescript import aliases not working in VSCode

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, next.js, alias, tsconfig

I'm currently building a NextJS template and trying to configure import aliases.

**tsconfig.json** aliases-related part:

```
"baseUrl": "./src",
"paths": {
  "@api/*": ["api/*"],
  "@components/*": ["components/*"],
  "@constants/*": ["constants/*"],
  "@pages/*": ["pages/*"],
  "@store": ["store"],
  "@store/*": ["store/*"],
  "@styles/*": ["styles/*"],
  "@util/*": ["util/*"]
}
```

**Folder structure**:

[image]

**The problem**: VSCode alias importing not working properly.

E.g. in *_app.tsx*, alias import for Redux store is working properly:

[image]

**1. Problem**: alias import for exported type *State* from *Navigation.slice.ts* is not working.

Exported type:

[image]

VSCode import in *Navigation.selectors.ts*:

[image]

Also here it can be seen that exported constant *RootState* from *src/store/reducer.ts* is working properly. The fact that alias import sometimes works and sometimes doesn't is really confusing.

**2. Problem**: Import for exported constant *navigationReducer* from *Navigation.slice.ts* inside *reducer.ts* not working at all.

Exported constant *navigationReducer*:

[image]

VSCode import in *reducer.ts* not working at all:

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated!